# Which probability distribution will you use to model outliers?

Tags: probability

I was asked this question in a recent interview for the position of a Data Scientist:  Which probability distribution will you use to model outliers ?

I told him outliers are like rare events which can be modelled by a Poisson distribution. I pretty sure I'm wrong and the interviewer seemed to think the same. But I don't know the answer to this.

Please advise.

Comment: Based on standard deviations of a standard normal distribution it is well possible to describe outliers (usually something beyond 3 standard deviations) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score. Opinion: There is no „one true“ answer for the question described by you, its just „testing“. Speaking about right-skewed poisson will be okay, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is Gaussian distribution. This is a famous approach that is used in Anomaly Detection. What you do is to fit your feature to the Gaussian distribution and the samples which have the probability below the specific threshold are labeled as an outlier.

Quoting from the paper [Modeling Outlier Score Distributions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-35527-1_59):

> Many existing unsupervised outlier detection algorithms calculate some kind
> of score per data object which serves as a measure of the degree of outlier. Scores are used in ranking data points such that the top n points are considered
> as outliers. For example, the statistical-based approach proposed in [4], uses
> a Gaussian mixture model to represent normal behavior and each datum is
> given a score on the basis of changes in the model. A high score indicates a high
> possibility of being an outlier.

[Example of usage - 1](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/a-gaussian-approach-to-detection-of-anomalous-behavior-in-server-computers-c70f7c3c1d94#:%7E:text=One%20such%20common%20approach%20for,by%20Gaussian%2FNormal%20Distribution%20Function.).

[Example of usage - 2](https://towardsdatascience.com/wondering-how-to-build-an-anomaly-detection-model-87d28e50309)